# What causes the Leaflet JS Providers error; Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {time}

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet providers and attempting to add the NASAGIBS.ViirsEarthAtNight2012 to my layer control, my other basemaps load fine; but this one doesn't and returns the following errors in the console.  What could cause this?

Code Sample;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var aLayerOne = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://hot.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">Humanitarian OpenStreetMap Team</a>'
    });

    var aLayerTwo = L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'

    });

    var NASAGIBS_ViirsEarthAtNight2012 = L.tileLayer('http://map1.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-webmerc/VIIRS_CityLights_2012/default/{time}/{tilematrixset}{maxZoom}/{z}/{y}/{x}.{format}',{
    attribution: 'Imagery provided by services from the Global Imagery Browse Services (GIBS), operated by the NASA/GSFC/Earth Science Data and Information System (<a href="https://earthdata.nasa.gov">ESDIS</a>) with funding provided by NASA/HQ.'
    });



    var map = L.map('myMap', {
        center: centerlatlng,
        zoom: 4,
        layers: [aLayerOne],
        //maxBounds: bounds


    });


     markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    var points = L.geoJson(geojsonfeatures, {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Destinatio);
        }
    });
    markers.addLayer(points);

    var promise = $.getJSON('js/weatherstations.js');
    promise.then(
        function(response) {
            console.log('promise success handler', response);
            var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(response);
            geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log('promise error handler', error);
        }
    );


    // Add a Layers Control
    var baseMaps = {
        "Humanitarian Open Street Map": aLayerOne,
        "Esri Imagery": aLayerTwo, 
        "Night Vision": NASAGIBS_ViirsEarthAtNight2012,
    };

    var overLays = {

        "Destinations": markers
```

`Uncaught Error: No value provided for variable {time}(anonymous function) @ leaflet.js:6o.Util.template @ leaflet.js:6o.TileLayer.o.Class.extend.getTileUrl @ leaflet.js:7o.TileLayer.o.Class.extend._loadTile @ leaflet.js:7o.TileLayer.o.Class.extend._addTile @ leaflet.js:7o.TileLayer.o.Class.extend._addTilesFromCenterOut @ leaflet.js:7o.TileLayer.o.Class.extend._update @ leaflet.js:7s @ leaflet.js:6o.Mixin.Events.fireEvent @ leaflet.js:6o.Map.o.Class.extend.invalidateSize @ leaflet.js:6(anonymous function) @ leaflet.js:6o.Util.bind @ leaflet.js:6`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out; the parameters are needed which reference the URL.

`var NASAGIBS_ViirsEarthAtNight2012 = L.tileLayer('http://map1.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-webmerc/VIIRS_CityLights_2012/default/{time}/{tilematrixset}{maxZoom}/{z}/{y}/{x}.{format}', {
    attribution: 'Imagery provided by services from the Global Imagery Browse Services (GIBS), operated by the NASA/GSFC/Earth Science Data and Information System (<a href="https://earthdata.nasa.gov">ESDIS</a>) with funding provided by NASA/HQ.',
    bounds: [[-85.0511287776, -179.999999975], [85.0511287776, 179.999999975]],
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 12,
    format: 'png',
    time: '',
    tilematrixset: 'GoogleMapsCompatible_Level'
});`